# How to configure a module after installation

Tags: 7

In my Drupal 6 website there are a bunch of modules. What is the simplest way to configure these modules? Also I am not sure of where their settings are? If there is a simple link that can be invoked to configure them , that will be awesome. In this case its the ctools module.
I am not looking for http://www.sitename.com/admin/by-module neither the Site building has the module.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to the module itself to present configuration options, and in Drupal 6 these can be a bit harder to find. I definitely recommend installing the admin_menu module (http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu), which can provide expanding drop-down menus to easily browse through all of the admin-side links.

With cTools specifically, the base 'Chaos tools' module won't do anything on its own, though it can be required by other contrib modules. If you're looking to use one of the bundled modules such as Stylizer or Page Manager, you'll need to enable and configure those modules separately.

Comment: Akalata, thanks for the quick answer. I wanted to look at Chaos Tools (CTools) AJAX Example . I enabled it but do not know now how to run it or use it. Any clue?

Comment: Also there was a link I once used that had the config in it that usually brought up the config options for a module.

Comment: many of the 'example' and 'starter' modules have example code with lots of comments, in order to help you write your own module. I took a brief look at ctools_ajax_example.module, and that appears to be what this is also -- not a GUI-configurable tool, but a guide to writing  your own module (in this case, dependent on the ctools ajax library).

Comment: (last comment submitted early, but it's a good enough break).

Other example/starter modules:

Suite of core examples:
http://drupal.org/project/examples

The Token module also comes with a build-your-own submodule:
http://drupal.org/project/token

Comment: Thanks for your answers and help but I was looking for www.website.com/admin/settings/modulename which will work for most cases. But also remember to set the permission on www.website.com/user/permission.

Answer (score -1):

[your website domain]/ctools_ajax_sample
You don't really configure that module, but you can see it in action after it's been activated.